# How to delete elements with regex in BaseX

Tags: regex, xquery, basex

I have a  BaseX database that has the following format

```
<root>
    <node1>
        <value1>abctetabc</value1>
        <value2>...</value2>
    </node1>
    <node1>
        <value1>abctatabc</value1>
        <value2>...</value2>
    </node1>
</root>
```

I would like to ask about how can I delete nodes that their value includes tet.
Have I to use regex?

the normal delete is executed like this

```
XQUERY delete root/node1[value1='abctatabc']
```

How can I do a search for a substring?

Comment: Please note that title and the text of your question do not really match, so I’m not sure if you want to find or delete nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete nodes in a database, you can use `delete node root/node1[value1='abctatabc']` (see [XQuery Update](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update) in the BaseX documentation). If you want to delete it without changing the original document, you can use the `update` keyword:

```
document {
  <root>
      <node1>
          <value1>abctetabc</value1>
          <value2>...</value2>
      </node1>
      <node1>
          <value1>abctatabc</value1>
          <value2>...</value2>
      </node1>
  </root>
} update {
  delete node root/node1[value1 = 'abctatabc']
}
```

Of course you can also look for substrings (via [`fn:contains`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_contains.html)) or use regular expressions (via [`fn:matches`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_matches.html)):

```
delete node root/node1[matches(value1, 'abc')]
```